# Integration of two-class Cauchy distributions

Tags: integration

Consider Cauchy distributions in a two-class one-dimensional classification
problem:

$$P(x\mid w_i )=\frac{1}{πb}\frac{1}{1+((x-a_i)/b)^2}, i=1,2; a_2>a_1$$

By explicit integration, show that the distributions are normalized.

I tried to solve this by introducing a new variable:

$$u= \frac{x-a_i} b$$
$$ \Longrightarrow \frac 1 {\pi b} \int \frac 1 {1+u^2} \, du= \frac{\arctan⁡ u} {\pi b} $$

First, I don't know how to continue it. if I replace $\pi/2$ for the arctan in infinity, I have:

$$ ?? = \frac{1}{2b} + \frac{1}{2b} = b$$

Second, there are two distributions, so I don't know how to employ $b$, $a_1$, and $a_2$

Comment: I think you forgot $b$ in the expression for $du$. Namely, $dx=bdu$ and the $b$'s cancel. Then you get $\arctan u/\pi$ between $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ which is $(\pi/2-(-\pi/2))/\pi=1$. This works for both $a_i$ (normalization is not affected by translation)

Comment: If $u = \dfrac{x-a} b$ then you have $du = \dfrac {dx} b.$ So $$ \frac 1 {\pi b} \int \frac {dx}{ 1 + \left( \frac{x-a} b \right)^2} = \underbrace{ \frac 1 \pi \int \frac {du}{1+u^2}}_{\text{No “$b$'' appears here.}}. $$